# How to check if the user has enabled or disabled gps service during runtime in android?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I have an app where I need to get user's location. So at the start of the app, i have checked if the GPS is turned on or not. If yes, the user will easily log in to the app. If not, the alert dialog will be shown where user will be asked to turn it on. If the user denies, the app will close, if the user accepts to turn on gps, the user will be navigated to location settings. However, i am unable to track if the user has turned the gps on or not after the user reaches location settings. How do i do that ? This is my alert box code:

```
if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            AlertDialog dialog = new     AlertDialog.Builder(login.this).setTitle("GPS NOT ENABLED!")
                    .setMessage("Plese, turn on your gps to login to the app")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                            dialog.dismiss();


                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                            finish();

                        }
                    })

                    .setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
                                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP &&
                                    !event.isCanceled()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                finish();

                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I have implemented in below fashion.

1.Create an `interface`:

```
public interface GpsInterface {
    void onGpsStatusChanged(boolean gpsStatus);
}
```

2.Create a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class GpsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

private GpsInterface gpsInterface = null;
private Context context;
public GpsListener(){}

public GpsListener(Context ctx, GpsInterface gpsInterface){
    this.gpsInterface = gpsInterface;
    this.context = ctx;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        gpsInterface.onGpsStatusChanged(true);
    }else{
        gpsInterface.onGpsStatusChanged(false);
    }
}
}
```

3.Implement the `GpsInterface` in your class/activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GpsInterface{
    private GpsListener gpsListener;
    private boolean isGpsOn;

    //other stuff
}

    //in onCreate()
    IntentFilter mfilter = new IntentFilter(
            "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");
    gpsListener = new GpsListener(getActivity(), this);
    registerReceiver(gpsListener, mfilter);
```

Implement the `onGpsStatusChanged()` method in the activity

```
@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(boolean gpsStatus) {
    Logger.e("GPS STATUS", "ON " + gpsStatus);
    isGpsOn = gpsStatus;
}
```

4.Unregister your broadcast receiver in `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(gpsListener);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to check whether gps provider and network providers are enabled or not.

```
LocationManager lm =     (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

try {
gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {}

try {
network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {}

if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
// notify user
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
    dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int     paramInt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(  Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
            //get gps
        }
    });
dialog.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.Cancel), new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    dialog.show();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to check GPS status during runtime.

1. Create a Broadcast Receiver

   ```
   private BroadcastReceiver mGPSConnectivityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

       // GPS ON

       } else {

       // GPS OFF

       }
     }
   };
   ```
2. Register the Broadcast Receiver in onStart()

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();

       registerReceiver(mGPSConnectivityReceiver,
           new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));

   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to unregister the Receiver in onStop()!

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();

       unregisterReceiver(mGPSConnectivityReceiver);

   }
   ```

   This is probably the easiest and cleanest solution for this problem. I really hope that it helps!